# Show Off - Beautiful programmed jQuery Plugins

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, jquery-plugins

besides jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile - What are you choices for beautiful programmed jQuery Plugins. I'm currently developing my first plugin and try to learn from the best :-)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/) page.  He is a jquery plugin guru.